# Why does Pidgin kill itself when marked as offline?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, pidgin

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 netbook with Pidgin 2.6.6. Whenever I lose my WiFi connection or I mark Pidgin as offline, Pidgin does just that, but also quits itself. This is very irritating when I use my netbook in the car and when I walk in and out of WiFi coverage.

I have Away On Lock, Message Notification, Libnotify Popups, GTalk Invisible, and Buddy State Notification installed, if that matters.

Comment: Run it in a terminal and find out.

Comment: Segmentation fault isn't much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all of my packages were up to date, I would first disable all of Pidgin's plugins to ensure that they were not causing some sort of conflict.

If this did not work, I would try upgrading. While Ubuntu 10.04 is using Pidgin 2.6.6, the latest stable version of Pidgin is 2.7.3. You could build it from source, or install version 2.7.1 from Pidgin's PPA using [their instructions](http://www.pidgin.im/download/ubuntu/).

Comment: It's always the plugins.